# Limit in DynamoDB using PHP SDK getIterator

Tags: php, amazon-dynamodb

I want to retrieve only last 10 itens of table 'notifications'.

```
$iterator = $dynoClient->getIterator(
    'Scan', array(
        'TableName' => 'notifications',
        'Limit' => 10,
        'ScanFilter' => array(
            "idTo" => array(
                "AttributeValueList" => array(
                    array('N' => $_SESSION['VISITORDATA']['idUser'])
                ),
                "ComparisonOperator" => "EQ"
            )
        ),
    )
);
```

Why this query still getting all itens and not only 10?

UPDATE

I tried the Jeremy`s suggestion:

```
$iterator = $dynoClient->getIterator(
    'Scan', array(
        'TableName' => 'notifications',
        'Limit' => 10,
        'ScanFilter' => array(
            "idTo" => array(
                "AttributeValueList" => array(
                    array('N' => $_SESSION['VISITORDATA']['idUser'])
                ),
                "ComparisonOperator" => "EQ"
            )
        ),
    ), 
    array(
        'Limit' => 10 
    )
);
```

but I'm still getting all itens, not only 10.

After this I iterate

```
foreach ($iterator as $item) { $res[] = $item->toArray(); }
```

My

> count($res);

should be only 10.

Comment: In the 3rd argument "limit" should be lowercase. That is probably a bit confusing, but it is documented that way.

Comment: Instead of using that 3rd argument, you could also accomplish the same thing with a [`LimitIterator`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.limititerator.php). Basically you would wrap the Scan iterator: `$iterator = new \LimitIterator($iterator, 0, 10);`

Comment: @rafael-freitas-darrigo the 3rd parameter in @jeremy-lindblom 's suggestion must have lowercased keys as `array('limit' => 10)` instead of `..'Limit' => ..`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Limit parameter does not limit the iterator, it is a parameter passed through to the Scan operation. This basically causes the iterator to make a lot of requests that each only return 10 items. To limit the iterator, as well, you need to set a limit using the 3rd argument of `getIterator` ([see docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/feature-iterators.html#basic-configuration)).

```
$iterator = $dynoClient->getIterator(
    'Scan', // operation name
    array( // operation params
        'TableName' => 'notifications',
        'Limit' => 10,
        // ...
    ),
    array('limit' => 10), // iterator options
);
```

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, this works with lower case. The client doesn't limit how much it gathers in one request, this is the job of the iterator.

> `$iterator = $dynoClient->getIterator(
>       'Scan', array(
>           'TableName' => 'notifications',
>           'Limit' => 10,
>           'ScanFilter' => array(
>               "idTo" => array(
>                   "AttributeValueList" => array(
>                       array('N' => $_SESSION['VISITORDATA']['idUser'])
>                   ),
>                   "ComparisonOperator" => "EQ"
>               )
>           ),
>       ), 
>       array(
>           'limit' => 10 
>       )
>   );`